# Kivy: Turning an App into a widget

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I have built a Kivy GUI using the 'App' class that is designed to load a file using a file chooser and make it into a list. I have now learned that my whole chunk of code needs to be converted to a widget so that it can be integrated into an existing GUI scaffold. I am not sure how to go about 'widget-ifying' my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my main.py file:

```css
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import os
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class OptionMenu(GridLayout):

    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()
        self.dismiss_popup()   

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()
class GraphMenu(GridLayout):
    pass
class UnnamedMenu(GridLayout):
    pass

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)



class MainController(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rt = MainController()
        return rt
Factory.register('Main', cls=MainController)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is my main.kv file:

```css
#kivy 1.0
<OptionMenu>
    cols: 2
 row:10
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.05
        text: "Input File"
        on_release: self.parent.show_load()
 Button:
  size_hint_y:0.05
  text:"Save File"
  on_release:self.parent.show_save()
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
  text:''
 RstDocument:
  text: text_input.text
  show_errors: True

<MainController>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Accordion:
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            orientation: 'vertical'
            AccordionItem:
                title:'Options'
                OptionMenu:
                    id: 'AppOpt'
   AccordionItem:
    title:'Config'
    UnnamedMenu:
     id:ConfigTab
   AccordionItem:
    title:'Graph'
    GraphMenu:
     id:GraphTab

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.7
            Label:
                
<scroller>

        
<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 10
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question, your App does nothing special and all the functionality is in the MainController widget. What more separation do you need than that?

```
Factory.register('Main', cls=MainController)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)
```

Also, these Factory lines are unnecessary, widgets automatically register themselves.

Comment: Thanks.Honestly, its not clear in the documentation that widgets do that